# I/flutter ( 7313): DioException [bad response]: The request returned an invalid status code of 400

Tags: flutter, paypal

I tried to add a payment mehtod with paymob
this is my code

1. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H0PbA.png)

```
1. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5FJem.png)
```

this is my code:

``

1. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Obl85.png)

1. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/frAV5.png)

1. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qItE1.png)

```
this is my error: 
I/flutter ( 7313): DioException [bad response]: The request returned an invalid status code of 400.
```

Comment: Don't share screenshots or images of the code or errors. Kindly update your question properly with [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and what you have tried so far